# Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

Upgraded to use com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0. After that my application crashes with the exception 'Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton'.

It refers to my XML-file, ln 52, which is:

```
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/orientation_portrait"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="@dimen/medium_fontsize"
android:button="@drawable/smartly_checkbox"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tablet_p"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/orientation_checkbox_padding"
android:drawablePadding="@dimen/orientation_checkbox_padding"
android:text="@string/orientation_portrait"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/paragraph_spacing"/>
```

What is wrong with my XML?

Full stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: no.sensio.smartly, PID: 12892
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{no.sensio.smartly/no.sensio.activities.ProjectSelectionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
   at no.sensio.activities.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:136)
   at no.sensio.activities.ProjectSelectionActivity.onCreate(ProjectSelectionActivity.java:77)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
   at no.sensio.activities.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:136) 
   at no.sensio.activities.ProjectSelectionActivity.onCreate(ProjectSelectionActivity.java:77) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020067 a=-1 r=0x7f020067}
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:806)
   at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
   at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68)
   at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:63)
   at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:59)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
   at no.sensio.activities.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:136) 
   at no.sensio.activities.ProjectSelectionActivity.onCreate(ProjectSelectionActivity.java:77) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your smartly_checkbox.xml

Comment: clean your project and try to rebuild.

Comment: Hey, just as a quick test - can you get rid of `android:button="@drawable/smartly_checkbox"` - and see if the XML get inflated. I am suspecting this might be the cause - perhaps defining a custom style might work. But please let me know if removing `android:button` solves the error - we can take it from there.

Comment: Try removing `android:button="@drawable/smartly_checkbox"` .

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this ?